# textproto repeating several times, ways to avoid?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I have a `.textproto` file that repeats the same block several times. Is there a way for me to declare a variable and then call it several times?

Specifically, I have:

```
abc {
   efg {
      orange: true
      purple: false
   }

}

xyz {
   efg {
      orange: true
      purple: false
   }

}

mnt {
   efg {
      orange: true
      purple: false
   }

}
```

you see `efg` block is being repeated several times. Is there a way for me to avoid this repetitiveness?

Answer (score 0):

Not while sticking to the "standard"<sup>[1]</sup> text format, no.

It's not a full-fledged data templating language in the style of [Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/) or [YAML](https://yaml.org/), with support for references to entities defined elsewhere in the document. Instead, it's purely a text-based serialization format for protobuf messages. If your concrete output message must have a section repeated verbatim, then so must your source `.textproto` file as well.

If you're willing to change the structure of the message you wish to encode to not involve repetition (perhaps by including a section for named "definitions", and a field to refer to them), you can naturally avoid repetition in the `.textproto` version of the message as well. Otherwise, you need to use another format.

Since there is a well-defined and intuitive [JSON serialization form](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json) for protocol buffers (as of proto3), by using that as an intermediate representation, you could leverage one of the existing JSON-compatible languages, such as the already-mentioned Jsonnet. It would look something like this, for your example message:

```
local colors = {
  orange: true,
  purple: false
};

{
  abc: {
    efg: colors
  },
  xyz: {
    efg: colors
  },
  mnt: {
    efg: colors
  }
}
```

(There are also other ways to achieve that in Jsonnet, such as by using inheritance, if you want to avoid repeating the `efg` key too.)

---

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> AIUI, there's no canonical definition of the text format, and indeed different protobuf language implementations may have some minor differences in how they interpret corner cases.</sup>